# time calculation in xslt

Tags: xslt

I am using xsl version 2.0

I have a time field that I need to add 1 to.
I am getting a formatted number from the the below node:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="Master/End/Timecode"/>
    <xsl:text>
```

The data in "Master/End/Timecode" looks like 01:00:00:00 
basically time-- hours :minutes :seconds :frames
the frames are a count from oo to 23. How to add 1 to the frames and have the seconds and minuts increment up if frames=23.

Example 01:00:59:23 plus 1 would give a result of 01:01:00:00.
Any ideas

Answer (score 2):

Just convert it to frames, increment, and then convert back:

```
  <xsl:analyze-string select="Master/End/Timecode" regex="^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$">
    <xsl:matching-substring>

      <!-- Split into components -->
      <xsl:variable name="hours"
                    select="xs:integer(regex-group(1))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="minutes"
                    select="xs:integer(regex-group(2))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="seconds"
                    select="xs:integer(regex-group(3))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="frames"
                    select="xs:integer(regex-group(4))"/>

      <!-- Calculate total amount of frames -->
      <xsl:variable name="total-frames"
                    select="$hours * 60 * 60 * 24 +
                            $minutes * 60 * 24 +
                            $seconds * 24 +
                            $frames "/>

      <!-- Add 1 frame -->
      <xsl:variable name="remaining-frames"
                    select="$total-frames + 1"/>

      <!-- Calculate new component values -->
      <xsl:variable name="new-hours"
                    select="$remaining-frames idiv (60 * 60 * 24)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="remaining-frames"
                    select="$remaining-frames mod (60 * 60 * 24)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="new-minutes"
                    select="$remaining-frames idiv (60 * 24)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="remaining-frames"
                    select="$remaining-frames mod (60 * 24)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="new-seconds"
                    select="$remaining-frames idiv 24"/>
      <xsl:variable name="new-frames"
                    select="$remaining-frames mod 24"/>

      <!-- Recombine components -->
      <xsl:value-of select="$new-hours"/>
      <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$new-minutes"/>
      <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$new-seconds"/>
      <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$new-frames"/>

    </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
```

Comment: are the commands analyze-string and regex valid commands for the sablotron processor?

Comment: No, Sablotron is an XSLT 1.0 processor; `analyze-string` and friends are all parts of XSLT 2.0. That said, you specifically mentioned that you're using XSLT 2.0 in the question, so now I'm confused, since you cannot possibly do it with Sablotron.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to this. Learning as I go. I will look for a xslt processor and try again. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The only decent XSLT 2.0 processor is Saxon, IMO (http://saxon.sourceforge.net/). There's also Altova, but it's slower and non-cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you'd either want to write a [custom XPath function](http://www.google.com/search?q=custom+saxon+function) for, or [process outside of XSLT](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+and+xml). There are ways you could make this happen but they get very complex, very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The correct translation algorithm milliseconds (SSS) in HH: mm: ss: ff
The above is not true.

```
Developed an algorithm: z = 8415
ch=z idiv (60*60*25)
m=(z-ch*60*60*25) idiv (60*25)
s=(z-ch*60*60*25-m*60*25) idiv 25
f=(z-ch*60*60*25-m*60*25-s*25)

Total: 0:5:36:15
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that can be done by my XSLT timecode library: https://github.com/sshaw/xslt-timecode. 
With it, you can do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:tc="http://screenstaring.com/xslt/timecode">

<xsl:import href="timecode.xsl"/>

<xsl:call-template name="tc:add">
  <xsl:with-param name="timecode1">01:00:00:00</xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="timecode2">00:00:00:01</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>

<!-- Or -->

<xsl:variable name="frames">
  <xsl:call-template name="tc:to-frames">
    <xsl:with-param name="timecode">01:00:00:00</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="fps">23.97</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="plus-one">
  <xsl:call-template name="tc:from-frames">
    <xsl:with-param name="frames" select="$frames + 1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="fps">23.97</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Sadly you can't just add 1, though `multiply` and `divide` support integer operands so `add` should probably support it too.